# Can you identify this, possibly Italian, uniform?

Tags: identification, uniform, italian

I'm trying to identify this uniform and info on the men. My grandfather is in the picture.

I'm told it's from WWI in Italy.

Can someone help me on this. My grandfather was born in 1901.

[image]

Comment: Any further information you can give? Like which country he served for, what unit or kind of unit he served with, where they fought, what rank he was/made, etc? Any info you have might help narrow the search and save a lot of other people some time (a little time adds up when you multiply it by a lot of people).

Comment: If he was born in 1901 he is unlikely to have served in WWI, but would presumably have been conscripted shortly after the war ended - possibly this is what the photo shows?

Comment: well I heard WW1 went from around 1914 to 1918, so being a 16, 17 year old, at that time would be a possibility. IDK

Comment: T.E.D. I really don't have much more information other than finding the negative in a frame of my grandparents wedding. I'm trying to identify the uniform and go from there & thought maybe this site can help.

Comment: They definitely look like Italian army uniforms, of about the WWI period.